# Emulator Api 19 faster than Emulator Api 27

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have an app which downloads data from a PHP Server using Threads with ExecutorService. I have tested the app in various emulators and runs just fine.

What i noticed is that in Emulator with API 19 the app downloads data and finishes faster than the Emulator with API 27. Both run the exact same code.

**Note**
Both emulators are same. Same ram,cores e.t.c. Only the android version is different.

How is that possible for the API 19 to finish quicker? Is the android version or is something else?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Newer emulators require hardware acceleration, if you have an Intel processor you need **HAXM**, if you have an AMD one you need the **Hypervisor**. Check out the Requirements section [on this page](https://www.andreszsogon.com/using-android-8-and-9-emulators-without-android-studio/#requirements) for details and links.